# I want to create a Flutter app that can interact with pc via USB, but I found nothing online

Tags: android, windows, flutter, adb, serial-communication

basically the main goal is to make an app that can show the sensors data. the sensors values(CPU, GPU) temps are to be fetched from HWINFO. I found an app(PITIKAPP) that does the job but the problem is it creates a server and talks to app on the server, but it affects the online gameplay(packet loss).
if someone could provide me the direction on how to make my pc communicate with the android phone via USB, that would be a great help.
for example the apps that are used to extend the desktop screen uses USB to get data from pc.

Comment: You can use network connections through USB, by advising to forward TCP or UDP ports from/to the phone. Check the adb documentation on `adb forward` and `adb reverse`.

Comment: thanks for the heads up but it is still very confusing to me, I have created bunch of apps that works as standalone, but this is something new to me